# Efficient algorithm to get all binary combinations with k 1s

Tags: algorithm, performance, binary

I have *n* bits and I know that *k* of them are ones.
The result I should expect from the algorithm with *n* = 4 and *k* = 2 is:

```
1100
1010
1001
0110
0101
0011
```

I already attempted some recursive strategies, but none of them are efficient enough for my needs (*n* might be > 50000).
I have also seen the answers to similar questions, but they are not efficient enough.

I thought that I can get something working fast by capitalizing the fact that 1s and 0s are not different, so I could avoid a lot of iterations that would yield the same result.
Similarly, I have noticed that I can avoid to compute up to half the results since most of them are just the binary opposite of one another (i.e. 1100 -> 0011).

Comment: n might be up to 50000...  It doesn't really make sense to say "get all" when you figure out how many there might be.  Are you sure you don't mean "count".

Comment: What is your value of k when n = 50,000? At that size, even a modest k could have a staggeringly huge number of combinations.

Comment: Usually k is a bit less than half the value, so if n is 50,000, usually k is 20,000 or similar.

Comment: Good luck with processing the output for those numbers. Do you have any idea how many bit patterns that represents? Think of the number of atoms in the universe... There is no efficiency good enough when your *output* is going to have a huge size. For *n = 50000, k = 6*, the number of bit patterns is 1084657180984679023259666700000. As each pattern has 50000 bits, we are thus talking about more than [6 billion yottabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte)

Comment: The complexity cannot be lower than the number of got numbers, C(n, k)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use `std::next_permutation`, you should find something else than std::string to use as your type though.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
void Permute(int n = 8, int k = 3) {
    std::string s = std::string(n-k, '0')+std::string(k, '1');
    do {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}

00000111
00001011
00001101
00001110
00010011
00010101
00010110
00011001
00011010
00011100
00100011
00100101
00100110
00101001
00101010
00101100
00110001
00110010
00110100
00111000
01000011
01000101
01000110
01001001
01001010
01001100
01010001
01010010
01010100
01011000
01100001
01100010
01100100
01101000
01110000
10000011
10000101
10000110
10001001
10001010
10001100
10010001
10010010
10010100
10011000
10100001
10100010
10100100
10101000
10110000
11000001
11000010
11000100
11001000
11010000
11100000
```